# Given the Matrix for the Linear Transformation T. Calculate T(v)

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have been given the matrix

$$A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 8 & -17 \\
    3 & 2 & -2 \\
    -3 & -6 & 9 \\
    1 & -4 & 7 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

which is the matrix of the linear transformation T. I have also been given the vector

$$v = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\
    0 \\
    -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and am supposed to calculate T(v). Overall, I'm a bit confused on how to solve this honestly, but I'm thinking about somehow making row reductions for [A v], but in order to do this I'll have to transpose A to get the dimensions right, does that make any sense or have I gotten it all wrong?

Any input is very much appreciated!

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Why don't you just compute $A.v$?

Comment: Please properly typeset your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is basically unreadable with your matrix written like that. Also there must be a mistake in your question, as $A$ defines a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and you are trying to compute its value on a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I think he's writing the matrix in row-major order, so the transformation is well-defined. But agreed to everything about MathJax.

Comment: Sorry about that, the syntax has been edited :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos , I'm pretty new to matrices, what does A.v mean? Is that the same as putting A on the left-hand-side and v on the right-hand-side?

Comment: @Nickewas Yes. And write $v$ as a column, not as a row.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay, but then the dimensions won't match? v only contains three rows while A contains four rows or maybe I misunderstood

Comment: @Nickewas Then forget what I wrote. The problem just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product $A\cdot v$  is a new vector  the coordinates thereof  are the dot products of the rows of $A$ by the vector $v$.

For instance, the first coordinate of $A\cdot v$ is 
$$1\cdot 3+8\cdot 0 -17\cdot (-3)= 54.$$

Similarly, the coefficients of the product of  an $m{\times} n$ matrix $A$ by an $n{\times}p$ matrix $B$ are the dot products of the rows of $A$ by the columns of $B$.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to transpose A in order to compute it, the dimensions are fine.

By definition, the product AB is defined for $A_{n\times k},B_{k\times l}$, and in your case, the dimensions of A are $4\times 3$ and the vector is $3\times 1$, so the product is well defined.

A is the matrix representing T, so $T(v)$ is $Av$ (in the right basis), So $T(v)$ is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 8 & -17\\
3 & 2 & -1\\
-4 & -6 & 9\\
1 & -4 & 7
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
0\\
-3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\cdot3+8\cdot0-17\cdot(-3)\\
3\cdot3+2\cdot0-1\cdot(-3)\\
-4\cdot3-6\cdot0+9\cdot(-3)\\
1\cdot3-4\cdot0+7\cdot(-3)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
54\\
12\\
-39\\
-18
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So your answer (in the basis the matrix is given at) is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
54\\
12\\
-39\\
-18
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks, when do you transpose matrices?